# Is it possible to override a driver that has been compiled into the kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a USB device for which I have an API.  This API only works if the USB device doesn't use the ftdi_sio/usbserial drivers.

On my laptop, if I plug the USB device in, these drivers get loaded (as modules) and I have to unload them using modprobe -r after which code using the API can see the device.

I have another device which experiences the same issue although no modules are loaded so I'm guessing these drivers are compiled into the kernel.  My question is this - is there any way to stop this device from using these drivers or do I have to recompile the kernel, etc?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are essentially looking for a way to :

- **unbind** the default driver from your USB device
  *and*
- **bind** a driver of your choice to it.

Take a quick look at [**this**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12005/how-to-use-linux-kernel-driver-bind-unbind-interface-for-usb-hid-devices) to get you started.

A slightly more detailed description of the same is available in this excellent [LWN article of (un)binding device drivers](http://lwn.net/Articles/143397/).

Comment: Excellent stuff, TheCodeArtist.  Sending the USB ID to the unbind command in /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio worked perfectly and allowed by application to access the USB device.  Thanks!

Comment: @dermur how did you manage that, I have problem with the ftdi device uarts revoke problem, device not sees attached usb device only last one active with the multiple devices.